# Storing cookies and referencing variables

Tags: php, cookies

Im storing the users country in a cookie and then changing the content depending on that variable.

If the country cookie isnt set, then I use their IP to get their country code.
I've also provided a drop down so they can manual reset their country.

My issue is that cookie doesn't seem to set until after the page loads.
For example, the initial value of the cookie is 'US', I set it to 'GB' and then echo it.
'US' is echoed despite just changing it to 'GB', until I refresh the page and then it switches to 'GB'.

The problem with this is that when the visitor switches to GB for example, it stays on US until they refresh the page again.

Does anyone know how to fix the problem explained above?

Thank you

```
<?php
if(!isset($_COOKIE['Country'])) {
    /* Collect Country Code */
}   

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $country = $_POST['country'];
    setcookie('Country', $country, time()+60*60*24*30);
    $country = $_COOKIE["Country"];
}

echo $country;
?>
```

Comment: you can update cookie through JS, without submitting to server.

Answer (score 0):

Well, by default the cookie's value is always returned in the next page load within PHP, the reason is that cookie values are sent by the browser when the page request loads and subsequently are only resent on the next request, so the change only reflects when the next page request comes in. Read the PHP Manual on setcookie - http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php and it will tell you this in the first paragraph

Logically, if I were writing this code, I don't know why you are trying to read back a form value from a cookie in the first place.

```
$country = $_COOKIE['Country'];
if isset($_POST['submit']) {
   $country = $_POST['country']; //sets up $country for current page
   setcookie('Country', $country, time()+60*60*24*30); //sets up $country for subsequent page loads
}
```

$country will reflect the user's country preference for the rest of the page and the cookie value is set for any subsequent pages that the user refers to. Instead of referring to the cookie superglobal for any code i.e. $_COOKIE['Country'], set your code to look for $country (the local variable) instead. I think that your problem will then be solved.